# Dropping GWT token from URL

Tags: url, gwt, dns, token

When working with GWT Activities and Places, is it possible to not display the token, e.g. ":myToken" in the URL as seen below.

From:
http://domain.com/page/#HelloPlace:myToken

To:
http://domain.com/page/#HelloPlace

Many thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The tokens are required for history support in the application when using the built in MVP architecture, I don't think you can remove them unless you only want to have one screen in your application.

Answer (score 0):

See [HyperLink.setTargetHistoryToken() documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html?overview-summary.html) javadoc.

You can use an [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html?overview-summary.html) is you don't need history processing.